# Gentoo apache configuration. virtual hosts problem

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, gentoo

I use LAMP and add to it virtual host ololo.loc!
when I use links http://ololo.loc it works and i can see file from /var/www/ololo.loc/
when I use localhost in links it works too and i can see file from /var/www - default folder!
but when i connect to my local web server from notebook
when i use my local ip - it works with /var/www
when i paste ololo.loc i see again file from /var/www
hosts at notebook and server is ok:

```
127.0.0.1        www.ololo.loc ololo.loc #server
192.168.1.4      www.ololo.loc ololo.loc #notebook
```

Vrtual host file is

```
<VirtualHost ololo.loc:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ololo.loc
    ServerAlias www.ololo.loc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>
```

i try to do it with ip into  like this  -same problem

where is the problem? sorry for my bad english. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

First, perhaps you can edit your question and differentiate olololo into different letters for the domain part. abcde.com is just a lot better to read.

Second, do NOT give the same IP addresses to different hostnames in /etc/hosts.

Third, /var/www/ololo.loc/ is not visible anywhere in your configuration.

Fourth, what is "/var/www - default folder"? /var/www/html?